# basicHttpBinding ReceiveTimeout of client

Tags: c#, wcf, timeout, basichttpbinding, channelfactory

I'm trying to get a clear explanation of what ReceiveTimeout of a basicHttpBinding will do on my client side? Not the web service side.

It's pretty clear in the MS docs that this property will have no effect in the WCFBinding of a client. But how about basicHttpBinding? Does this property make a difference when its set for the basicHttpBinding that my ChannelFactory is using?

Answer (score 0):

When you are reusing resources - making multiple calls using your channelFactory - this will determine how long it can be inactive for and keep its connection open